# How to make a network listener in python?

Tags: python-3.x, http, networking

I'm trying to build a network listener in python, which is able to capture the local network traffic from my own computer.

I've tried with sockets, but i find it very hard to use this method, because i'm not on a Linux-machine.

So, is there another method i'm not aware of, now when it's about only monitoring my own traffic? :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called sniffer, try scapy framework.